# Datos en misma pagina

Tags: php

Dispongo de una lista:

```php
<ul>
<?php

$link->set_charset("utf8");
$sql       = ("SELECT id, nombre FROM centros WHERE (zona='S9') order by nombre");
$resultado = $link->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
    if ($row['nombre']) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a href=";
        echo "menu.php?terma=";
        echo $row['id'];
        echo '>';
        echo strtoupper($row['nombre']);
        echo "</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Desde cualquier elección de la lista se dirige a otra página llamada menu.php y muestra los datos en una tab

Yo quisiera poner este tab en la misma página de la lista y que me muestre los datos aquí mismo.
Se podrá hacer ?

Comment: Sí se puede hacer, pero necesitas usar Ajax para llevar y traer los datos entre el cliente y el servidor. Aquí hay varios ejemplos de Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Editado**

A tu etiquetas de enlace puedes ponerle una única clase, para que así javascript sepa que datos obtener y de esa forma mostrar solo los datos de dicho enlace.

Algo así:

```php
<ul>
<?php

$link->set_charset("utf8");
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM centros WHERE zona='S9' order by nombre";
$resultado = $link->prepare($sql);
$resultado->execute(array());
while ($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['nombre']) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<a class='link' href=";
        echo "menu.php?terma=";
        echo $row['id'];
        echo '>';
        echo strtoupper($row['nombre']);
        echo "</a></li>";
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Y con JavaScript usando axios:

```html
<div id='box'><!-- aqui se mostaran los datos --></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
var box = document.getElementById('box');
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.link');
links.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var urlPage = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    axios.get(urlPage).then(function(res) {
      box.innerHTML = res.data;
    })
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: No me funciona, creo que debe ser por que apunta a menu.php y esa es la dirección que se supone vamos a eliminar. Creo que tiene que apuntar a si mismo. Gracias, Rimuru, te agradezco.

Comment: @charlie quizás sea por el query string `terma` quizás sea `tema`.

Comment: Lo modifiqué asi: echo "<a class='link' href=";
                               echo "?terma=";   y funciona bien apuntando al link correcto, pero no me muestra nada. Puse el script entre los head al principio. El div lo pongo en cualquier parte pero no me muestra nada. Gracias

Comment: La palabra terma está correcta. Se refiere a los nombres de lugares con agua termal (hot-spring). Para el caso corresponde a un código numérico, según como pinche en la lista.